# Normalization of one particle state wave function in fock space - commutator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, commutator, bosons, identical-particles

In deriving the 1/$\sqrt{N!}$ normalization factor the first step is looking at the one particle state (see image below). I am confused about how we got from the first line to the second? Maybe I am very rusty on QM... But how did the commutator get in there?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Please do not use images, use MathJax instead. Concerning your question: $a(x^\prime) |\Omega\rangle=0$ solves your problem.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with MathJaX, [here is a tutorial.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  It's basically a cousin of LaTeX adapted for web purposes.

Comment: In this notation,  is $|\Omega\rangle$ the vacuum/zero-particle-state? In that case, you can introduce a $-\hat{a}^{\dagger}(x)\hat{a}(x')$ for free, because $a$ annihilates the vacuum.